# Nativescript - handle emoji in TextField

Tags: nativescript, emoji

Have a textfield - user enters an emoji (displays correctly) - I save it to a string and then on next visit, populate the TextField with the saved string - get heiroglyphics.

This on both iOS and Android.

How do I need to process strings from TextField which contain emojis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to display it with special font, the most common is font awsome I think. And you can use it like:
 
https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fonticon

But instead of font awsome maybe you want something like:
https://emojisymbols.com/emojilist.php

I do not know if it is possible in a TextField thought. But because this if fonts it should theoretically be possible.

then for example =) will be replaced with a

Comment: Emojis are entered by the user into the TextField using their keyboard. It displays correctly. I save the text and next time I display the string in the TextField - it doesn't display. So pretty sure it's an encoding issue.